# How to skip ASP.Net form authentication of parent website on some ASP.Net MVC action of child website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have ASP.NET MVC website which is hosted in a child directory of other website which is protected with form login like below:

```
<domain>/parent          --asp.net 2.0, with login form (standard form auth)
<domain>/parent/mysite   --asp.net mvc 4.0
server: IIS 6
```

to enter the `mysite` website user should pass the login form of `parent` website. it is OK until we develop twilio application on `mysite` and **need a public access of twiml on `<domain>/parent/mysite/twilio/twiml`**. the `/twilio` is an area, `/twiml` is a controller.

i have tried the following configuration on the `/mysite` web.config but it doesn't work.

```
<location path="~/parent/mysite/twilio">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

**Edit**

i don't have control/access to change the code/configuration on parent website.

any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The parent app has forms auth. therefore it creates an encrypted cookie for the client browser, if you could decrypt this cookie in your child app then the child app could check to see if access should be granted.

The above makes lots of assumptions mainly that you are doing standard Microsoft forms auth, and if you are lucky also using standard Microsoft membership providers.

To enable you to decrypt the cookie you must set the machineKey to be the same in both apps, [This blog explains it.](http://colinmackay.co.uk/2013/07/10/authenticating-across-virtual-directories/)

I think you might have to upgrade your 2.0 app, but I don't know.

Comment: thank you for your response. yes i use standard microsoft forms auth. i have follow your provided link but still don't understand if it is fit mine. where should i put the code to check and grant access? because i think the login form is showing without touching the child code. no?

Comment: I don't know asp.net 2.0 well enough, however for me with 4 MVC 4.0 child apps, I simply used the same membership database for each child app (web.config) DefaultProvider ...... and set each machineKey to be the same. I didn't have to write code. I think you will find it the same as you are using the MS membership provider. But I think you will have to update the 2.0 code to use 4.0 esp. for the membership provider.